# How to extract the storage of a smart contract?

Tags: smart-contracts, contract, storage

How do I extract the storage data of a deployed smart contract? I am trying to read the storage data from the "free Ledger Nano S" contract `KT1BRudFZEXLYANgmZTka1xCDN5nWTMWY7SZ` from the Tezos Foundation, because I am interested in how it works. The contract code is pretty straight forward. TzScan for example doesn't show the storage data, all it shows is `Unit` which in this case is not useful. The solution from an old question [How to get smart-contract storage data?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/how-to-get-smart-contract-storage-data) doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the command line

`./tezos-client get contract storage for KT1BRudFZEXLYANgmZTka1xCDN5nWTMWY7SZ`

You could also just call the RPC

`curl http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/KT1BRudFZEXLYANgmZTka1xCDN5nWTMWY7SZ/storage`

Comment: This is of course assuming you are running a node by yourself. But this is what I was looking for. Thx 

Answer (score 2):

Let's find the contract on [Arronax](https://arronax-beta.cryptonomic.tech/?m=true&e=tezos/mainnet/accounts&q=eyJmaWVsZHMiOlsiYWNjb3VudF9pZCIsIm1hbmFnZXIiLCJzdG9yYWdlIiwic2NyaXB0Il0sInByZWRpY2F0ZXMiOlt7ImZpZWxkIjoiYWNjb3VudF9pZCIsIm9wZXJhdGlvbiI6ImVxIiwic2V0IjpbIktUMUJSdWRGWkVYTFlBTmdtWlRrYTF4Q0RONW5XVE1XWTdTWiJdLCJpbnZlcnNlIjpmYWxzZX1dLCJvcmRlckJ5IjpbeyJmaWVsZCI6ImJsb2NrX2xldmVsIiwiZGlyZWN0aW9uIjoiZGVzYyJ9XSwibGltaXQiOjUwMDB9) and look at its code...

```
storage unit;
code { CDR ;
       NIL operation ;
       AMOUNT ;
       PUSH mutez 0 ;
       { COMPARE ; EQ ; IF {} { SOURCE ; CONTRACT unit ; { IF_NONE { { UNIT ; FAILWITH } } {} } ; AMOUNT ; UNIT ; TRANSFER_TOKENS ; CONS } } ;
       PAIR }
```

..you will see that nothing is effectively being stored in the contract, which is why you're just getting `Unit`.